# How do I move items from one gridview to another gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two gridviews, and when the user highlights a row on the first gridview and clicks a button, it should move to the second gridview.

When I click on the button that record gets added but it only add the last row I've selected (if I select 20 rows, only the last gets added).

All records that are selected should be moved.

How do I do this in ASP.NET?

Comment: Would you share a code? We can't guess what you have written.

Comment: Tags combination looks strange.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: May be you Can achieve this by using checkboxes

Comment: @George: actually i have two grids, in the first grid some results are displayed by default, say a whole table is displayed, now i have a search option, whenever user searches some keywords, the first grid is re-populated, and now when user selects the row from first grid, it gets added to the second grid... now my issue is if the multiple rows with same id is selected by user, then only one record should be added, and user should not be allowed if he selects same row again. Please reply with some resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];

    dtItems.Columns.Add("city_ID");
    dtItems.Columns.Add("city_Name");
    dtItems.Columns.Add("status");
    dtItems.Columns.Add("date");

    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                DataRow row;
                row = dtItems.NewRow();

                row["city_ID"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                row["city_Name"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                row["status"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                row["date"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();

                dtItems.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }

    Form2 frm = new Form2(dtItems);
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

In Form2 copy this code:

```
public Form2(DataTable dtIt)
{
    dtItems = dtIt;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void AddEmptyRows()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        dataGV.Rows.Add();
    }
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddEmptyRows();

    for (int i = 0; i < dtItems.Rows.Count; i++) {
        dataGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dtItems.Rows[i]["city_ID"];
        dataGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dtItems.Rows[i]["city_Name"];
        dataGV.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dtItems.Rows[i]["status"];
        dataGV.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dtItems.Rows[i]["date"];
    }

    dataGV.Enabled = true;
}
```