# show the data from datagridview of one form to another form using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have a form and there is a datagridview control. i want that when i select a data from datagrid view then this data comes in the text box of any other form with the help of c#.

Comment: May be similar to this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332179/how-do-i-move-items-from-one-gridview-to-another-gridview/5359916#5359916

Comment: Is this a WinForms application, or asp.net?  If it is asp.net, I am not sure what you mean by "in the text box of any other form".

Comment: If it is WinForms, what is the asp.net tag doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  [http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/300367](http://this)

Comment: shruti i want for C# windows application and show in another from by the gridview.

Comment: ok then see this. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/8a5bdc53-0101-4e6a-bba4-dd6541f025b0/

Comment: SHRUTI i have done this code but when i click on gridview row then data does not come on other form textbox.

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: can u chat with me for helping me?

Comment: shruti plz help for this problem.

Comment: The way i find best to solve this sort of issue is to put a breakpoint  then you can step through and check how many values are within your collections and then check that value against the value that you are searching for. i m in my company so cant chat sorry.

Comment: how it is i m understanding shruti

Comment: private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            int selectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex];
            PatientFile pf = new PatientFile((DataRowView)selectedRow.DataBoundItem);
            pf.ShowDialog();
            
            
           
        }

Comment: in other form i try this                                                   DataRowView Data=null;
        public PatientFile(DataRowView dr)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Data=dr;
        }and in text changed even i try             txtdoctorid.Text = Data["DOCTOR_ID"].ToString();

Comment: error is index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index